# dlang how specify location of the external "C" library?

Tags: d, dub

I'd like to use [augeas](http://augeas.net/docs/api.html) on my Ubuntu. I've installed the `libaugeas-dev` apt package, that installed `augeas.h` file in  `/usr/include` directory. Now I'd like to call some augeas functions.

The first one is `augeas *aug_init(const char *root, const char *loadpath, unsigned int flags)`. I try to use it with the following code

```
import std.string;

struct augeas;

extern (C) augeas *aug_init(const char *root, const char *loadpath, uint flags);

void main() {
    auto x = aug_init(std.string.toStringz("/"), 
                  std.string.toStringz(""), 
                  0);   
}
```

The code compiles, but the linker cannot find the `aug_init` function (`undefined reference to`aug_init'`). How can I tell him to find it?

Answer (score 1):

All that was needed is to put the following entry in the `dub.json`:

```
"libs": ["augeas"]
```

So the whole `dub.json` is this:

```
{
    "name" : "aug-tool",
    "description" : "Hello World",
    "dependencies" : {  },
    "libs": ["augeas"]
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you just need to tell the linker to include the library. `dub` can do it. `dmd` can do it itself with two things: you can add `pragma(lib, "augeas");` to your source file you are compiling or `-L-laugeas` to the build command line. `gdc` and `ldc` also support the `-L-l` command I believe. Or if you link separately, just pass `-laugeas` to the `ld` command line.